# When to use is_nothrow_constructible?

Tags: c++

In what context does it become important to use `is_nothrow_constructible`? Why is it important and what purpose does it serve?

Comment: If something is nothrow, then often times it is simple, and simple has a better chance of being optimized.

Comment: What makes the question different from e.g. `is_constructible` or `is_trivially_constructible` or any other type trait? You need it for exactly what it says: When you need to know whether something is constructible from some arguments without it potentially throwing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main context you'll see it used in is to calculate whether a different function should be `noexcept`.

For instance, a constructor for `std::pair` might look like:

```cpp
template<typename T1, typename T2>
template<typename T, typename U>
pair<T1, T2>::pair(T&& x, U&& y)
  noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<T1, T&&> && std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<T2, U&&>)
   : first(std::forward<T>(x)), second(std::forward<U>(y)) {}
```

This means that `noexcept`-ness can be propagated out better, helping with some other optimizations.

---

One case where you might have completely different behaviour is [`std::move_if_noexcept`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move_if_noexcept). This uses `std::is_nothrow_constructible<T, T&&>` to decide whether something should be moved from or copied from.

It's used to maintain "strong exception guarantees". For example, when resizing a vector, it will move items to the new memory if it can't throw, otherwise it will copy (if a copy throws, the original is still in tact).

Comment: So with this, pair would be mimicking the throw/no-throw behavior of the template parameters? 
Do you have an idea what the optimization gains from usage scenarios like then one you show?

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you are implementing `new` for whatever reason. If the constructor cannot throw then you can simply allocate memory and perform placement new. All done.

Now if the constructor can throw you have to add a guard that frees the allocated memory in case exception occurs in the constructor.

What if it is a `new[]` that allocates an array of some type? Then if elements of the array can throw upon construction then you ought to ensure that the guard is aware of exactly how many elements were constructed and destroy them upon exception, in addition to freeing the memory.

Well, usually one doesn't need to implement `new` but what about custom `vector` class or some other container you desire to that allocates memory manually and uses placement new in various operations?

In this situation you can use the trait to optimize the cases when the constructor doesn't throw.

Comment: The compiler should be able to optimize out exception handling if something is noexcept anyways, without explicitly checking `is_nothrow_constructible`: https://godbolt.org/z/b6nqbKaxW

Comment: @Artyer only if it is something trivial and not a completely different piece of code. In STL they write something very overcomplicated to deal with moves that can throw.